# What is the best way to calculate percentage of an iterating operation?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I've written a function that saves all numbers between two digit groups to a text file, with a step option to save some space and time, and I couldn't figure out how to show a percentage value, so I tried this.

```
for length in range(int(limit_min), int(limit_max) + 1):

    percent_quotient = 0
    j=0
    while j <= (int(length * "9")):
        while len(str(j)) < length:
            j = "0" + str(j)  

        percent_quotient+=1
        j = int(j) + int(step)  # increasing dummy variable

for length in range(int(limit_min), int(limit_max) + 1):
    counter=1
    i = 0
    while i <= (int(length * "9")):
        while len(str(i)) < length:
            i = "0" + str(i)  #

        print "Writing %s to file. Progress: %.2f percent." % (str(i),(float(counter)/percent_quotient)*100)
        a.write(str(i) + "\n")  # this is where everything actually gets written
        i = int(i) + int(step)  # increasing i
        counter+=1
    if length != int(limit_max):
        print "Length %i done. Moving on to length of %i." % (length, length + 1)
    else:
        print "Length %i done." % (length)
a.close()  # closing file stream
print "All done. Closed file stream. New file size: %.2f megabytes." % (os.path.getsize(path) / float((1024 ** 2)))
print "Returning to main..."
```

What I tried to do here was make the program do an iteration as many times as it would usually do it, but instead of writing to a file, I just made percent_quotient variable count how many times iteration is actually going to be repeated. (I called `j` dummy variable since it's there only to break the loop; I'm sorry if there is another expression for this.) The second part is the actual work and I put counter variable, and I divide it with `percent_quotient` and multiply with 100 to get a percentage.

The problem is, when I tried to make a dictionary from length of 1 to length of 8, it actually took a minute to count everything. I imagine it would take much longer if I wanted to make even bigger dictionary.

My question is, is there a better/faster way of doing this?

Comment: Your post had a bit of an intimidating length to it so I trimmed out some of the background story that I feel a lot of users here would perceive as irrelevant. Hope I haven't cut too much. Of course as the asker you are free to revert my edit (as are a number of other users here based on their rep).

Comment: No, everything cool, I'm sorry.

In fact, thank you, I figure more people would evade it if they found it too long as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the step variable is giving me a lot of headache, but without it, this would be the right way to calculate how many numbers are going to be written.

```
percent_quota=0  #starting value    
for i in range(limit_min,limit_max+1):  #we make sure all lengths are covered
    percent_quota+=(10**i)-1  #we subtract 1 because for length of 2, max is 99
```

TessellatingHeckler, thank you, your answer helped me figure this out!

Answer (score 3):

I can't really work out what this is doing. But it looks like it's doing roughly this:

```
a = file('d:/whatever.txt', 'wb')
limit_min = 1
limit_max = 5
step = 2

percent_quotient = (10 ** (limit_max - limit_min)) / step

for i in range(limit_min, 10**limit_max, step):
    output = str(i).zfill(limit_max) + '\r\n'
    a.write(output)

    if i % 100 < 2:
        print "Writing %s to file. Progress: %.2f percent." % (str(i),(float(i)/percent_quotient)*100)

a.close()
```

If that's right, then I suggest:

- Do less code looping and more math
- Use `string.zfill()` instead of `while len(str(num)) < length: "0" + str(num)`
- Don't overwhelm the console with output every single number, only print a status update every hundred numbers, or every thousand numbers, or so.
- Do less `str(int(str(int(str(int(str(int(...`
- Avoid `"" + blah` inside tight loops, if possible, it causes strings to be rebuilt every time and it's particularly slow.

Comment: As I watch my version climb past 1400% complete and counting... lol. I should probably do more math myself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everything seems a little confusing since I'm seeing some methods like zfill() for the first time.

Not sure if percent_quotient is good since it is affected by step.

Let me try to describe it briefly. (sorry if I got something wrong here)
Basically, output of my program would be:0,2,4,6,8,00,02,04,06,08 all the way up to 99994,99996,99998.(with \n of course)
In your case, I think when "i" gets to the end of the loop and becomes 10**limit_max, percent actually equals 100*limit_min.
In this case, it would be 100%, but what if limit_min was 2 for example?

Comment: However, your code has helped me greatly, and in case I got something wrong, I'm sorry.
I'll study this in the morning and try to run it, just in case I misunderstood something. 

Let me wait for another answer or two, just to collect some more info, but other than that, I got it.
Less looping, more math. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted the answer before I saw the comment. But you sir made me laugh hard!

Comment: Sorry, it's late in the day. Mine won't do `0,2,4,6,8,00,02,04,06,08` as the output, it just counts using the step but always the same number of digits in the output: `0002, 0004, 0006, 0008, 0010`, like that. Then I don't understand the pattern - can you edit your original question so the code runs - adding some example `limit_min, limit_max, step` values that you are trying?

Comment: Well, if you set limit_min to 1 and limit_max to 2 and step to 1 for example.
Step=1 means no numbers are skipped, as the next value of iterating variable in the loop equals itself plus step.
So, it's going to print not all numbers, but all possible number combinations, so you could test/demonstrate how weak number passwords are.
Basically, my problem is, it takes some time for it to calculate the percentage quotient, but you actually brought my eureka moment.

Comment: So basically, I think my answer is:
for i in range(limit_min,limit_max+1):
   percent_quota+= 10**i/step.
Would this be ok?
By the way, how do you grey out the code part, I don't know how to use it in the comments, so it looks all messy. Sorry